# Protreptic to Philosophy of Language?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

I have a friend who is quite interested in language, the idea of language, and so on. I myself am a philosophy student but one who has not done much reading in phil of language. I'd like to find some resources for them to check out on phil of language, as I think it might be of interest to them, and am looking to solicit recommendations herein.

Their general interests seem to be around how it is that languages reflect different worldviews. A non-technical, but in my view still philosophically significant, example is to be found in the movie Arrival (2016), where the the aliens' complex sets of thoughts are communicated via an abstract image, which the researchers eventually find out is their form of written communication. Another example is how for some cultures when asked how a person is doing, their actual individual contentedness is considered secondary to the fact that they are blessed by God, as in the case of the Arabic alhamdulillah. And, general interests surrounding why it is that some things cannot be translated directly, etc.

I am asking this here with the hopes that I'll be able to get something beyond simply an introductory text to phil of language. Rather, I am interested to see if anyone has any recommendations where the author specifies *why* phil of language is to be considered of interest. What problems it addresses itself to that linguistics studies does not, or cannot. This is obviously done frequently in introductory texts, and so if anyone has a particular one in mind, that will be helpful, but perhaps this is also to be found in articles, essays, etc. The main criteria is that this is not someone who reads in philosophy, so it must be (1) not overly technical and (2) not simply an explanation of why phil of language is of importance to philosophy more widely conceived, but why phil of language should be of interest to anybody, regardless of pre-existing interest in philosophy.

Thanks

Comment: How about a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMA1G6Mb0Y0&t=691s

Comment: Let me know when you can study philosophy completely without language ;)

Comment: Look at the "further reading" list to [Wikipedia's Sapir-Whorf hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity), particularly short essay [How Does Our Language Shape The Way We Think?](https://www.edge.org/conversation/how-does-our-language-shape-the-way-we-think) and [Deutscher's book Through the Language Glass: Why the World Looks Different in Other Languages](https://books.google.com/books?id=6NOjIzNZvosC). But the pop stuff "of interest to anybody" is not what philosophy of language really addresses itself to.

Comment: @curiousdannii, I knew that was coming my way!

Comment: @Conifold and Ameet Sharma, thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: "The Geography of Thought" by Richard Nesbitt. Google it as there are free downloads available now.